# Fetching getter method name in java

Tags: java

The class Test  is POJO class .I want to get  getter method name of Test class.

`String methodName=test.getXXX();`

How to get method name XXX into variable 'methodName' from above code.

Comment: Maybe `String methodName = "getXXX"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the a private variable holding the name of the last executed method current method in the `getXXX()` body.

For example:

```
class POJO {
    private String lastMethod;

    public String getXXX() {
        this.lastMethod = "XXX";
        return "some value";
    }
    public String getLastMethod() {
        return this.lastMethod;
    }
}
```

That way, you can do this instead and get the method name:

```
String myValue = test.getXXX();
String methodCalled = test.getLastMethod();
```